# Using Matomo API to get top 10 visited pages starting with a certain URL

Tags: matomo

For a weblog I am trying to get the top 10 popular posts from for example the last month. I figured I'd get the data out of Matomo, as that's already tracking visits and has an API. I've never used this API before though, so I've been reading the documentation and trying out some things. I am able to get data from the API using the `Actions.getPageUrls` method. However, when I try to filter using `segment=^http://example.org/post` I still get data from other URL's. It looks like it filters on session and gives back all data from the sessions that have at least 1 page that conforms to the filter.

The full URL I'm using is: `http://example.org/matomo/index.php?&module=API&token_auth=12345&method=Actions.getPageUrls&format=json&idSite=1&period=month&date=today&expanded=1&segment=pageUrl%3D%5Ehttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.org%252Fpost`. I've also tried with less and no URL encoding for the segment, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. If I use a URL that doesn't exist I get an empty array returned.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to only get the top pages with a URL starting with http://example.org/post? Or do I have to sift through the data myself to only get the pages I want?

I am using Matomo version 3.13.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. There is no need to use `segment`. This can be achieved using the `flat`, `filter_column` and `filter_pattern` parameters.

Setting `flat=1` will make it so all pages are returned in a single array, instead of hierarchically.

With `filter_column` and `filter_pattern` I can filter the results.

The URL I use now is: `http://example.org/matomo/index.php?&module=API&token_auth=12345&method=Actions.getPageUrls&format=json&idSite=1&period=month&date=today&flat=1&filter_column=label&filter_pattern=%5E%2Fpost%2F`. This does exactly what I want.

The unencoded pattern is `^/post/`, so this will filter out any page that does not start with `/post/`.